# Asp.net charts- multiple y values

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a stacked bar chart where I want to display two values for the Y parameter at the method :

```
public void DataBindXY(
    IEnumerable xValue,
    string xField,
    IEnumerable yValue,
    string yFields
)
```

My problem is that I would like to have two values for Y and not just one, as mentioned at  [MS documentation][1]

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd488523.aspx  , I tried putting at the yField parameter two values , and I am keep getting "You can only set 1 Y values for this data point. Parameter name: yValue"

here is an example of my code , while DV is a DataView object with three parameters, two applicable for Y axis and one applicable for X axis:

```
Points.DataBindXY(dv, "Xfield", dv, "Yfield1,Yfield2");
```

Thanks, David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to make it aware that your series needs 2 Y values, so just try setting

```
Chart1.Series[0].YValuesPerPoint = 2;
```

But as per [Stacked Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456771.aspx) it only allows a single Y value per point.

In case you are looking for the values to be stacked up, then i think you would need equivalent number of series as the number of stacks you want which would then be rendered based upon their common X Values.

> Series 1 --> Xfield,Yfield1
>
> Series 2 --> Xfield,Yfield2